# Don't show run tab after launch in Android Studio

Tags: tabs, android-studio

I'm developing apps in Android Studio. But everytime I hit Run button, the Run tab pops up automatically from bottom with messages like Installing com.packagename etc..., Success, Launching

I've already disabled automatic displayin of Android DDMS tab (because I use DDMS from toolbar which opens new window) by editing configurations. But I can't disable this stupid automatic Run tab showing.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no standard way of achieving this but I found an interesting workaround mentioned below and using the same.

When your run tab is opened, Instead of hiding it using right-top corner button, Drag it till it hides.

Like in picture shown below

[image]

Now Run your project run window wont appear, When you want it back click on run button in horizontal bar.

Working perfectly for me .

Comment: thanks :) it's workaround but kind of works, so I'm going to accept it

Comment: @bakua sometimes wrong ways take us to a right destination :)

Comment: why can't I add more than one upvote? This is one of those things which is not really important, but annoys you every single time you see it.

Comment: this fixed for it me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986530/android-studio-emulator-in-a-separate-window

Comment: Since at least 2023 there IS a standard way (and simple), described in a very clear way here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76355664/1986583

Answer (score 107):

In case anyone still struggling with this annoying thing, there is a way to disable this annoying popup.

**Note:** this will remove the run tab altogether.

[image: Disable run tab]

So basically go to your Run/Debug configuration and Uncheck `Activate tool window` at the bottom.
This gets rid of the Run tab.

Comment: This works. In case anyone can't find it (me), the window scrolls down (duh).

Comment: To open the run/debug configuration, go to `Run` > `Edit configurations`. You can also click the "app" dropdown in the toolbar (next to the run button) and select "Edit configurations".

Comment: expand the window if not visible at first.

Answer (score 24):

To disable this annoying thing forever (within the current project), open **Run/Debug Configurations** and click **Edit configuration templates...**.
[image]

Scroll down to the bottom and uncheck `Activate tool window`.

[image]

Although to be honest, I've found no point in the Run tab at all, so I switched it off completely. It doesn't seem to be more useful than Logcat.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me, but I encountered another problem, which is in the editing layout screen, when selecting something(like textView), it takes about 4 seconds to display the attributes. Is there a solution? Unfortunately, this is the worst version of Android Studio :(

Comment: @mody What is your version of Android Studio? Mine is **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2**, and when I click on a widget in **Design** mode, it takes approximately a half of a second for the attributes of the widget to appear. Furthermore, it depends on how powerful your PC is. If the current version of Android Studio doesn't satisfy you, you can download any of the previous ones [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of Android Studio, and the specifications of my computer are good (16 GB RAM and Core i7 gen 10). After updating the latter, it takes about 4 seconds to show the attributes, and here I mean when choosing when clicking on the design screen, not the component tree

Answer (score 24):

Finally I find way to avoid come up runToolbar when press Shitf+F10:

just click to setting icon
[image]

next scroll down to disable "Active Tool Window" and press "OK"
[image]

Comment: It's great, but with many separate composable screens it becomes quite tedious.

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 11):

I have a workaround that show Logcat tab instead of Run tab.

From `Run` menu do `Edit Configurations… > Miscellaneous > Show logcat automatically`

[show Logcat tab instead of Run tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Un5HE.png)

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 and above:

In case you cannot find **setting icon** [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BUpf.png)
you can get to that setting by Run/Edit Configurations...
scroll down and untick **Activate tool window** [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf3wj.png).

Answer (score 0):

For a long time other advises to uncheck 'Activate tool window' was working good for me, until I started to work with Compose and use 'preview on device' - each preview has its own configuration, and this annoing 'Run' tab pops-up everytime and hides emulator window.
My solution in new Android Studio UI (Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2) is to:

1. move 'Run' tab to right bottom - right click on tab and select 'Move to -> Right bottom'.
2. drag 'Run' window all the way down, so that it's not visible.

After that, even though 'Run' tab still activates automatically on each app/preview run, but it remains minimized.

[image]

I don't know if it works the same in old UI, as mentioned previously, I'm using new one.

[image]