# Prevent ADB output from showing in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, adb

Whenever I run my app from within Android Studio, the ADB output is automatically shown in a tool window e.g.:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: asus-nexus_7
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Development\AndroidStudioProjects\example\main\build\apk\main-debug-unaligned.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.app
Installing com.example.app
```

I almost never need to actually read this output, but I can't find a way to prevent it from showing. If I edit the run configuration, I can prevent logcat from opening automatically, but not the ADB output.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm kind of missing the point why do you want to do that. It doesn't do anything bad, it's not like you're forced to read it.

Comment: It's just slightly annoying having something pop up every time I run the app, when I'm just going to close it again straight away. I agree, it's not like it's stopping me from developing but it's just a bit annoying :)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237561/dont-show-run-tab-after-launch-in-android-studio/21239381#21239381

Comment: Looks like it. I tried searching but didn't find that question. Seems that, at this time, there is no real way to solve this but at least a workaround exists. Not sure who is eligible to close questions as duplicates but feel free. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, the logcat one can be solved by editing your run configurations.

[image]

From Run > Edit Configurations, select your Android run configuration from the menu on the left, and switch to the logcat tab. Uncheck the "Show logcat automatically" box and hit apply.

Then you'll have to deal with the issue of hiding the "Run" tool window, of which the only workaround I know is to resize it until it's not visible.

Comment: (I am the author of the question) I mentioned that in my question, though. I think you're right that the only option is to resize the Run tool window until it's not visible, as mentioned in the answer that pyus13 linked in the comments above.