# Android Studio Emulator in a Separate Window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm having a problem with my Android Studio. This is the first time that I installed Android Studio. The problem is that when I install any device it comes up with a grey background around the device or the emulator, I don't know if it has any thing to do with the latest Android Studio version, cause I have updated it, and the toolbar is at the top of the emulator instead of being at the top right of the device.

The first picture is how I want it to be, and the second picture is what appears when I open Android Studio and run my app on the device (emulator).

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 210, accepted):

In the second picture you have the emulator floated or windowed:

[image]

In order to get the emulator in a "separate" window go to *Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator* and uncheck *Launch in a tool window*:

[image]

Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#run-emulator-studio).

Answer (score 50):

Here is how to open the Android Studion Emulator in a separate window.

- Open Settings from `File` -> `Settings...`
- Select `Tools` -> `Emulator` and uncheck `Launch in a tool window`

[image: Uncheck Launch in a tool window]

Comment: This helped me to solve the issue of not seeing mobile type emulator on my laptop.

Answer (score 7):

There is a better idea to open as it opens in an older version of Android Studio.
[image]

If you open any project then close it. Open Virtual Device Manager.

[image]

It will look like this image
[image]

If you run it before opening any project then you will get a separate window emulator as it looks earlier. It will behave like a separate application. If you close the Android studio also it will remain open. You can close it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
To open the Android Studio emulator in a separate window, follow these steps:

1- Open Android Studio.
2- Go to File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences on macOS).
3- Click Tools > Emulator.
4- Uncheck the Launch in a tool window checkbox.
5- Click OK.
```

Comment: What's new in this answer, comparing with previous ones? Aside from putting everything into a code block for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

To enable a frame around the Android emulator to make it look like a real device, do the following: Open the **Virtual Device Manager** in Android Studio -> choose your device and click "**Edit this AVD**" -> **Show Advanced Settings** -> Scroll down to *Device Frame* and choose a skin for your device -> **Finish**.